# How to pass knowledge of what button was pressed to a p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I'm trying to help users fill in entity Id numbers on a submittal form.  I can't use a pulldown because there are 1000's.

In a PF dialog, I'm able to copy a selected value to the main form but I'm hardcoding the actionaListener into the commandLink to tell the popup dialog which h:textInput box on the main form to copy the value to and to render. If I have three h:inputText boxes I would then need to duplicate three p:dialogs.

For example in my p:dialog I would have a column in the datatable as such:

```
 <h:commandLink value="Select This Item" onclick="PF('dlg').hide()">
    <f:ajax render=":myForm:text_field_1" event="click"
    listener="#{bean.popDownId1(item.id)}" />
 </h:commandLink>
```

How can I pass those variables `myForm:text_field_1` (the form name and field) to the p:dialog so that it becomes a more generic popup dialog? Also is there a way to not have to code a listener method for each field (popDownId1, popDownId2, etc...)As a bonus I'd also like to externalize the dialog and include it in every xhtml page instead of cutting and pasting as I'm doing now.

Here is more actual code:

## form.xhtml

```
<h:form id="myForm">
   <h:panelGrid columns="3">
     <p:outputLabel value="Manager Employee Number: " />
     <h:panelGroup>
 <p:inputText id="managerId"
    title="Type Employee Id or click the ? to search for their Id"
    value="#{bean.department.manager}" >
    <f:validator validatorId="com.company.app.EmployeeIdValidator" />
 </p:inputText>&nbsp;
 <p:commandButton title="Click here if you don't know their Employee Number" 
    id="managerId" value="Lookup Id"
    onclick="PF('dlgManager').show();" type="button" >
    </p:commandButton>
   other fields and submit button
   </h:form>

  <p:dialog id="popup" modal="false" widgetVar="dlgManager" dynamic="true" >
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Employee Number Finder" />
     </f:facet>
     <p>Search using any keyword.</p>
     <h:form>
       Keyword: <p:inputText id="search" value="#{employeeSearch.searchString}" />
       <p:commandButton value="Search"
       action="#{employeeSearch.searchByKeyword}">
       <f:ajax execute="@form" render="output" />
       </p:commandButton> (Enter keywords separated by spaces)


     <p:dataTable id="output" var="employee" value="#{employeeSearch.employees}">

 <p:column headerText="Action">

    <h:commandLink value="Select" onclick="PF('dlgManager').hide()">
    <f:ajax render=":myForm:managerId" event="click"
        listener="#{bean.popDownManagerId(employee.id)}" />
    </h:commandLink>
</p:column>
    other columns(employee name, phone number, etc...)
    </p:dialog>
```

you can see that I'd need to copy the dialog and tweak it a bit for every field on my form where I want to do an employee number lookup.

onclick="PF(**'dlgManager'**).show();">
onclick="PF(**'dlgSupervisor'**).show();">
onclick="PF(**'dlgFloorChief'**).show();">

## EDIT

When applying BalusC's answer, if I add a second lookup Id button, the popup dialog to select an employee id has a command link which is tied to only the ManagerId field

`action="#{bean.popDownManagerId(employee.id)}"`

Also, when the second lookup id button is pressed the previous search results are still listed so the select command link would be referencing the wrong field to update

[image]

## popup dialog

[image]

Comment: Did you check the showcase ? The `data` and `messages` examples might inspire you more.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/message.xhtml
And remember, you can always pass more than one argument with a custom method signature..